sentiment analysis model testing in GOOGLE COLAB
import pickle

# Load the trained sentiment analysis model from the pickle file
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)

# Sample text for testing
sample_text = "I loved the movie, it was fantastic!"

# Predict the sentiment of the sample text
predicted_sentiment = model.predict([sample_text])

# Print the predicted sentiment
if predicted_sentiment == 1:
    print("Positive sentiment")
elif predicted_sentiment == 0:
    print("Neutral sentiment")
else:
    print("Negative sentiment")


/////////////////////ERRORS OUTPUT/////
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-75efef964cce> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 
     10 # Predict the sentiment of the sample text
---> 11 predicted_sentiment = model.predict([sample_text])
     12 
     13 # Print the predicted sentiment

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

Sentiment model analysis testing errors encountered when tyring to run those lines of code above for trying to test in a new sentence

Hi @Pulcheria,The error message "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'" indicates that the variable model is likely None when you try to use the predict method on it.Make sure the file named "model.pkl" exists in the same directory as your Python script.Ensure the file you're trying to load is actually a pickled sentiment analysis model.
Verify you're using the correct library for unpickling the model (usually pickle).If you trained the model yourself, there might have been an error during training that resulted in None being saved to the pickle file.
